# FlexBuilder 3 - ActionScript Only - AIR Application

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air, verifyerror

Using an ActionScript only project for AIR dev in FlexBuilder 3. I've already gone through the setup of changing the .mxml to .as to generate the main working file. I've also used NativeWindow.stage to get access for addChild, etc. Is there something I'm missing? When I try to use any flex codebase, there are always 'VerifyErrors'. Also, with ApplicationUpdaterUI there are also 'VerifyErrors'. Cannot find "mx.core.ByteArrayAsset". If I use the same code, but with MXML as the base everything compiles fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Okay, not sure this qualifies as a solution since it's limiting...but, I was using the latest milestone build of Flex 4 SDK ( 4.0.0.10485 ). I've switched back to using the 3.2 SDK and everything compiles correctly. Anyone have similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking the .as files generated from the working .mxml by defining the compiler option "-keep" in project properties. Then at least you could see what makes them different from the .as files you have created to see where things go wrong.